# MongoDB update a subdocument attribute

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

Let me start by saying I'm sorry if this has been answered, but I can't get other questions on this site to fit my needs and, more importantly, work.

I have the below example document, with a subdocument of 'address':

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("....")
    ,"addresses" : 
        [{
            "start" : ISODate("1973-07-10T00:11:51.111Z")
            ,"value" : "123 long road"
        }] 
}
```

What I need to do is to close the existing address record with an `end` attribute, and add a new line for the new address with a new `start` and `value` attribute. Eventually, I'll need to do this again so the code needs to update the subdocument record where `end` does not exist.

The below code does not work, but it's about as far as I can get:

```
db.sites.update(
      {"_id" : ObjectId("....")
        , "addresses.end" : {"$exists" : false}}
     ,{"$set": {"addresses.$.end" : "fdsa"}});
```

This gives the error:

```
Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juste replace in your query `"addresses.end" : {"$exists" : false}` with:

```
addresses: {$elemMatch: {end: {$exists: false}}}
```

Comment: Brilliant, the lot of you. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Guys, it seems that using addresses.$.end in conjunction with $elemMatch only ever updates the first subdocument, and not the one which was a missing end attribute. any ideas how to always update the subdocument that doesn't have an end attribute?

Comment: It works for me. It updates the first subdocument with a missing `end` attribute... Are you sure you do not have several subdocuments with a missing `end` attribute?

Comment: Got it working too, I had another condition that was never true. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Query should be more specific

**Updated **

```
db.sites.update ( {"_id" : ObjectId("...."), addresses: { "$elemMatch" : { end:{$exists : false}} } }, {"$set": {"addresses.$.end" : "fdsa"}});

db.sites.find()
```

results:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53df93da560b7815e1237934"),
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "start" : ISODate("1973-07-10T00:11:51.111Z"),
            "value" : "123 long road",
            "end" : "fdsa"
        }
    ]
}
```

but you can update only one

Take a look http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj.S

You can t update more element in Array https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking: he wants to update the element that does not have and "end" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your address field is poorly defined. you need make it a subdocument or an array of subdocuments. ie { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("....")
    ,"addresses" : 
        [
           **{**
            "start" : ISODate("1973-07-10T00:11:51.111Z")
            ,"value" : "123 long road"
            **}**
        ] 
}

your query should then work!

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the curlies {} - they are there really, just hiding in my above post. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Barno is there a workaround doing multiple updates?